# UWP WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync() returns UserCancel and freezes the UI

Tags: c#, uwp, oauth-2.0

I'm building an UWP application and on a click button I'm trying to authenticate to Netatmo OAuth 2 API https://dev.netatmo.com/apidocumentation/oauth

The authentication windows is shown and automatically closed. The user interface is completely frozen and blocked.

I use `WebAuthenticationBroker` like that

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var state = Guid.NewGuid();
        String NetatmoURL = $"https://api.netatmo.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={clientId}&scope=read_homecoach&state={state}&response_type=code";
        System.Uri StartUri = new Uri(NetatmoURL);

        WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                                WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                                StartUri);
        var returnValue = string.Empty;
        switch (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus)
        {
            case WebAuthenticationStatus.Success:
                returnValue = WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString();
                break;

            case WebAuthenticationStatus.UserCancel:
            case WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp:
                returnValue = "HTTP Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString();
                break;

            default:
                returnValue = "Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Error)
    {
        //
        // Bad Parameter, SSL/TLS Errors and Network Unavailable errors are to be handled here.
        //
    }
}
```

`AuthenticateAsync()` return `UserCanceled` as value for `WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData`.

In windows event viewer, I have this error :

```
Faulting application name: PickerHost.Exe, version : 10.0.19041.1023, time stamp: 0x438361b0
Faulting module name: AuthBroker.dll, version : 10.0.19041.746, time stamp: 0x1705697f
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000001fca8
Faulting process id: 0x4930
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7940d0d388204
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\PickerHost.Exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\AuthBroker.dll
Report Id: 4ca6605d-18aa-43b0-b6af-9dfc8abed4cf
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

In Microsoft->Windows->WebAuth/Operational, I have an information message:
`Navigation canceled by user`

I changed `WebAuthenticationOptions` by all the options it offers and I added a redirect_uri that matches with the redirect_uri configure in Netatmo portal but it's always the same result:
`UserCancel`.
I tried the URL directly in chrome browser and it works.

Comment: Sounds like the code is correct. no exception, no error, just the result. Maybe needs to check the Authentication in win32 to confirm if it works in .net environment

Comment: What do you mean by "check the Authentication in win32" ?
I found a workaround [Github project](https://github.com/tebben/Netatmo-API-DOTNET) that seems work.
It doesn't use `WebAuthenticationBroker`.

I also found a nuget [Netatmo NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Netatmo/1.4.1) [Netatmo NuGet Github](https://github.com/Riges/Netatmo) that does the same things, so I think I'll drop the `WebAuthenticationBroker`.